# Suppose $z$ and $\omega$ are two complex numbers such that $|z|≤1$ and $|\omega|≤1$ and $|z+i\omega|=|z-i\omega|=2$. Find $|z|$ and $|\omega|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Suppose $z$ and $\omega$ are two complex numbers such that $|z|≤1$ and $|\omega|≤1$ and $|z+i\omega|=|z-i\omega|=2$. Find $|z|$ and $|\omega|$.

**My attempt:**

I squared the two given equations
$$|z+iω|^2=4 $$
Therefore $|z+iω||\overline z-i\overline ω|=4$. On simplifying,
$$z\overline z+iω\overline z-i\overline\omega z+ω\overline ω=4\tag{1}$$

Proceeding similarly for $|z-iω|=2$ we get another equation,call it $(2)$.

On adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$z\overline z+ω\overline ω=4\;\text{or}\; |z|²+|ω|²=4 $$

which cannot simultaneously satisfy $|z|≤1$ and $|ω|≤1$ but the answer given is $|z|=|ω|=1$. What is the mistake in my method?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $z=1$ and $w=1$ is a circle of radius 1,

Comment: Is there any mistake in my method?

Comment: Note that if there are no solutions then every solution satisfies $|z|=|ω|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this the old school way.  Suppose $z = r_1 e^{i\theta}$ and $w = r_2 e^{i\psi}$ with $0 \le r_1, r_2 \le 1$ and $0 \le \psi \le \theta \le 2\pi$ without loss of generality.  Then $$\begin{align}
|z+iw|^2 &= |(r_1 \cos \theta - r_2 \sin \psi) + i(r_1 \sin \theta + r_2 \cos \psi)|^2 \\
&= (r_1 \cos \theta - r_2 \sin \psi)^2 + (r_1 \sin \theta + r_2 \cos \psi)^2 \\
&= r_1^2 \cos^2 \theta + r_1 \sin^2 \theta + r_2^2 \sin^2 \psi + r_2^2 \cos^2 \psi - 2r_1 r_2 \cos \theta \sin \psi + 2r_1 r_2 \sin \theta \cos \psi \\
&= r_1^2 + r_2^2 + 2r_1 r_2 (\sin \theta \cos \psi - \cos \theta \sin \psi) \\
&= r_1^2 + r_2^2 + 2r_1 r_2 \sin (\theta - \psi).
 \end{align}$$
Similarly,
$$|z-iw|^2 = r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2r_1 r_2 \sin (\theta - \psi).$$
Thus $$4 = r_1^2 + r_2^2$$ which is impossible.  Essentially, this is the same as your solution, just written explicitly with real-valued variables throughout.

The difference of the two equations yields $$0 = 4 r_1 r_2 \sin (\theta - \psi),$$ which of course is only possible if $|z| = 0$ or $|w| = 0$ or $\theta - \psi = k \pi$ for some integer $k$.  It is trivial to dismiss the first two cases as these lead to immediate contradictions.  The last case would imply that $z = -w$ or $z = w$; in either case, this implies $$|z \pm iw| = |z(1 \pm i)| = \sqrt{2}|z| \le \sqrt{2} \cdot 1 = \sqrt{2},$$ again showing impossibility.

Comment: So is the answer given incorrect?

Comment: @DylanRodrigues Yes; the claim that such $z, w \in \mathbb C$ can be found is false.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s not the answer that’s incorrect, but the problem. If this is your teacher’s problem, he should be chastised; if it’s a book problem, the book should be thrown away.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that there are no solutions, but there are easier ways to see it.  $$2=|z+iw|<=|z|+|w|<=1+1\implies |z|=|w|=1$$

The only way that $|z+iw|$ can equal $2$ is if $z$ and $iw$ have the same argument.  By the same token, $z$ and $-iw$ have the same argument.  Then $iw$ and $-iw$ have the same argument, which is absurd.

Comment: Ah, the good old triangle inequality!

Comment: Right. The two equations are inconsistent. Either equation has enough information to solve the problem, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=iw$. The parallelogram law gives:

$$|z+v|^2+|z-v|^2= 2(|z|^2+|v|^2).$$

Hence

$$8=4+4=2(|z|^2+|v|^2) \le 2(1+1)=4,$$

a contradiction.

Conclusion: $z$ and $w$ with the above properties do not exist.